How to Convert Optional<String> to a Fixed UUID Value for Nulls in jOOQ During INSERT Operations?
I am working with a database that handles null values very poorly. Instead of using nullable strings, I want to use a fixed, very rare value (essentially a UUID) as a placeholder for null.
My goal is to use Optional instead of String for fields in Java, and whenever I bind an Optional.empty() to an INSERT INTO statement, I want jOOQ to automatically convert this to my UUID that I use as a flag for an empty optional. When the optional has a value, I want jOOQ to use the provided value as usual.
I tried setting up a converter, but it only seems to work during SELECT operations and not during the insertion phase. I suspect I might be missing something.
Here is what I have so far:
package com.res.jooq.neo4j;

public class Neo4jOptionalUtils {

    public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "empty-string-optional-ac4ea8cd-9128-4ee3-bb2c-48a1c239ffd2";

    private Neo4jOptionalUtils() {
        // private constructor to hide the implicit public one
    }

    public static String optional(String value) {
        return value == null ? EMPTY_STRING : value;
    }

    public static String fromOptional(String optional) {
        return EMPTY_STRING.equals(optional) ? null : optional;
    }
}

I am using this utility class to convert null values to my fixed UUID and vice versa.
How can I configure jOOQ to apply this conversion automatically during INSERT operations?
Is there a way to ensure that both SELECT and INSERT operations respect this conversion logic without manually converting each value?
EDIT: thanks to Lukas' answer I managed to get it done, here a gist https://gist.github.com/bonelli/9f3c24a30218be71c26a335c0ab17cc1

Using Optional as a field is controversial, so it might be better/cleaner to implement your own type.  This should help.

Thank you Andrew, my first attempt was to try and make a converter from String to String in order to convert null values to my null-meaning-token and viceversa. While it did work on SELECT when streaming results, it did not do anything to bind parameters on INSERT INTO, and I don't know why

"it did not do anything to bind parameters on INSERT INTO, and I don't know why" - Perhaps, better ask a question about that, though, make sure the issue you've encountered is reproducible.

if I was sure it were an issue I would have post an issue on JOOQ's GitHub, in this case I'm asking for help because I'm not an expert with customizing JOOQ, what's the matter with that?
Isn't this a site to ask help about tricky programming issues?

Anyway, since it seems like you are very knowledgable about JOOQ @LukasEder, would you mind pointing me to the correct doc page?
This only shows examples with SELECT:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.19/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/
And this doesn't show any query example at all:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.19/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/
even though I believe the second is the one that I need

Federico, I didn't downvote you. I just wanted to point you into the right direction. Your question doesn't show to me why things wouldn't work in your case. Converters work out of the box for all operations. But they don't in your case. I'm not seeing why they don't, in your case. So, I hinted at updating your question (or asking a new one), showing what you're doing exactly, because otherwise, I really can't help you. Does this make sense? I'm not sure if you need "the right doc page." There's nothing special about using converted data types in INSERT statements

So, this question seems to assume that there's a difference between using Field<U> references in INSERT or SELECT (where U is a converted user-defined type):

I tried setting up a converter, but it only seems to work during SELECT operations and not during the insertion phase. I suspect I might be missing something.
How can I configure jOOQ to apply this conversion automatically during INSERT operations?

The answer here is that no, you don't have to do anything special. Converted fields work everywhere, out of the box. You probably simply didn't use the converted field. Assuming you're using jOOQ's code generator, just use the field everywhere:
List<MyType> list =
ctx.select(T.CONVERTED)
   .from(T)
   .fetch(T.CONVERTED);

ctx.insertInto(T)
   .columns(T.CONVERTED)
   .values(new MyType()) // Works out of the box
   .execute();

I'll be happy to answer a follow-up question about what you did specifically, to help you find where you went wrong.

After you assured me that Converters were indeed the right tool for the job I wrote a complete sandbox class with my precise setup, and after a bit of tweaking I understood where I was having problems.
This is the gist with the code I managed to put together: https://gist.github.com/bonelli/9f3c24a30218be71c26a335c0ab17cc1
Finally my problem was a particular corner case for the experimental Neo4j JDBC Driver that do not translate some SQL statements to proper Cypher queries.
Thank you for your assistance Lukas
